# WPF App - Make Command bar responsive

Tags: c#, wpf, win-universal-app

This is the Microsoft's Mail app on Windows 10. This app is Universal App.

[image]

I'm making an WPF app for windows 7. And here is it

[image]

I want to make my application able to handle responsive. When we resize the Window, Some of "Reply All" will hide and appear on the More button.

Currently, I make an WrapPanel to make all "Reply All" button is arrange base on windows size. How to make it Collapse and it only appear when we click on More btton (Like the Microsoft's Mail App)

My problem is how to determine which button need to hide. And how to make is become a item on More Button

Comment: Instead of `WrapPanel`, you should use `ToolBar` control (it should be wrapped inside a `ToolBarTray` control). It has an element called `OverFlowButton` which will contain any controls that can't fit inside a ToolBar.

Comment: You right ! :D Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

As you say, things happen when you resize the windows. You should handle [Window.SizeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.sizechanged.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) event properly. 
And making the whole ui responsive is a very broad topic.

Comment: My problem is how to determine which button need to hide. And how to make is become a item on More Button